# Pressure transducer returns 2.4v at 0 psi when working with a 0.5v to 4.5v pressure transducer

Tags: arduino-mega, pressure

I have this pressure transducer:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07YZL6TYD?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

The transducer has a range of 0.5v to 4.5v which translates to 0 psi to 100 psi.

When I hook the transducer up to a Arduino boards analog pin, whose range is between 0 to 1024, it returns about 520 at 0 psi.

When I measure with a meter, it reads 2.4v which i think should not measure that much.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you could follow up and answer any questions posed in the comments or answers by editing your question with updated or improved data we would all appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Is the pressure sensor measuring relative pressure or absolute pressure?

Assuming the pressure sensor is measuring absolute pressure:

- 1 atmosphere is about 14 pounds per square inch (PSI).
- Altitude and weather change that so it is unreliable / not-constant.
  But for many uses it is close enough.
- (14/100 PSI * (4.5V - 0.4V)) + 0.4V = 0.546V + 0.4V = 0.946V

The expected voltage given the parameters in the question, assuming this is an absolute pressure sensor and that it has a linear response, should be near 1 Volt.  But it is over double that.  Consider checking the supply voltage to the sensor.  Also consider disconnecting the output of the sensor from the Arduino board and repeating the voltage measurement. Finally, make sure the above assumptions are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your pressure transducer has an initial offset voltage, typically 0.5V, it states Output: 0.5 - 4.5 V / 0 - 5 V. I would also expect the output to be about 4.5V at full pressure but this is only a SWAG as there is no data sheet available. It might have been a good price but was it worth all of the time it is taking you to determine if it is OK? Are the meter readings correct, I cannot determine that unless I know what type of output the transducer has. Is it actually analog, does it need a pull up resistor, output loading requirement, ???

If you cannot get the information from the vendor I think the only way you will really know is to connect several up and test them. There are several types of pressure transducers in this package, they are absolute (atmospheric pressure) and Gauge (PSIG) (Pounds Per Square Inch). The nice looking advertisement on your link does not give this or much other needed information such as what media is it compatible with other then a few.